# Retrieve correct camera-object coordinates with billboarding effect

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, vertex-shader

I am working to display text on world space with a [billboarding effect](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/) in OpenGL.

Normal display:

[image]

With billboarding effect, the text quad doesn't follow the red dot. Strangely, it does follow when the dots are along the x axis. I think changing the top three columns in the viewModel matrix distorts the camera-object position.

How can I extract the correct quad's coordinates from the viewModel matrix?

[image]

[image]

```
//billboard code
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{   
    //gl_Position = projection * view  * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);

    mat4 mv = view*model; //viewModel matrix

    mv[0][0] = 1.0; 
    mv[0][1] = 0.0; 
    mv[0][2] = 0.0;

    mv[1][0] = 0.0; 
    mv[1][1] = 1.0; 
    mv[1][2] = 0.0;

    mv[2][0] = 0.0; 
    mv[2][1] = 0.0; 
    mv[2][2] = 1.0;

    //mv[3][0] = model[3][0]; 
    //mv[3][1] = model[3][1];
    //mv[3][2] = model[3][2];

    gl_Position = projection * mv * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering a quad with the local origin in the middle? Are you sure that your model matrix has the correct translation?

Comment: no, my text quads have their origin at the top left corner. They are not particle quads. The text renders just fine in world space without any billboarding effect so I think my model matrix is correct.

Comment: I have the feeling that there is more to it than you show. Can you show how you use the shader? The matrix modifications are guaranteed to keep the local origin of your model fixed. The rotation happens around that origin.